# Synchronizing on an interned String

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

**use case example**

- I have a servlet that is receiving login requests.
- If a login is currently in process OR the user is already logged in, the servlet should abort and inform the caller.

**current design**

Taking inspiration from database sharding, I plan to use the first character of each userid as a synchronization key.

```
void login( String userid )
{
  String first = userid.substring(0, 1);
  synchronized( first.intern() )
  {
    // query the cache or database for a session token.
    // if session token exists, throw an exception
  }
}
```

**questions**

1. I understand that using *String#intern* might overflow the permgen space. In my case, the string being dumped into permgen is a single Unicode character. Am I safe in using interned strings this way ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/synchronizing-on-string-objects-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question: Perm gen should be able to code with 65,536 one character `String`s (should only be a few megs).

However:

- This clearly isn't going to work on multi-process systems.
- You run the risk of deadlock (if some other code is synchronising on such `String`s).
- It's really ugly.
- Really you want a proper throttling(!), which shouldn't be at all difficult.

Comment: How would it not work in a multi-processor machine ? Assuming there is only one JVM. If I use my own Locks, how does it differ from using an interned String (in a multi-processor machine)?

Comment: He did not say this will not work on a multi-processor machine. It will not work on a multi-process system, i.e. a system where you have multiple instances of the JVM running (either on a single computer or on multiple computers) - 'synchronized' does not work across JVMs.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The `PermGen` overflow is not an issue. However:

1. `String.intern()` is a heavyweight operation, since it requires locking the String constant pool. This will reduce your throughput;
2. More importantly, you will synchronise on objects which 'escape' your control, e.g. if a library you use has a

   ```
   synchronized ("a") {
      // do stuff
   }
   ```

block somewhere, you will deadlock without knowing it. It's more or less the same issue as synchronising on `Boolean` or `Integer` values. I suggest you use your own locks for this.

Comment: Thank you. I'm in the process of migrating my design to use custom locks.

Comment: `intern` is in a sense heavyweight, but when you are talking about using database connections and the such like, it is relatively tiny.