# Locking Cache Key without Locking the entire Cache

Tags: java, performance, caching, concurrency

I have servlets that caches user information rather then retrieving it from the user store on every request (shared Ehcache).  The issue I have is that if a client is multi-threaded and they make more then one simultaneous request, before they have been authenticated, then I get this in my log:

```
Retrieving User [Bob]
Retrieving User [Bob]
Retrieving User [Bob]
Returned [Bob] ...caching
Returned [Bob] ...caching
Returned [Bob] ...caching
```

What I would want is that the first request would call the user service, while the other two requests get blocked - and when the first request returns, and then caches the object, the other two requests go through:

```
Retrieving User [Bob]
blocking...
blocking...
Returned [Bob] ...caching
[Bob] found in cache
[Bob] found in cache
```

I've thought about locking on the String "Bob" (because due to interning it's always the same object right?).  Would that work?  And if so how do I keep track of the keys that actually exist in the cache and build a locking mechanism around them that would then return the valid object once it's retrieved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't guarantee that there will be no deadlock if you don't have exclusive control of your locks. Interned `String` are globally visible, so they are a poor candidate.

Instead, use a map between keys and their corresponding locks. You might use synchronized access to a concurrent map, or use a `ConcurrentMap`. I'm not sure which is cheaper, but I'd lean toward `ConcurrentMap` because it expresses your intent succinctly.

```
ReadWriteLock trial = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(fair);
ReadWriteLock lock = locks.putIfAbsent(key, trial);
if (lock == null) {
  /* The current thread won the race to create lock for key. */
  lock = trial;
}
```

(Using a `ReadWriteLock` is optional; with it, you could do something fancy like allowing concurrent reads of a cached value by multiple threads, yet still have another thread get an exclusive lock when the value needs to be updated.)

It might be expensive to create a lot of locks that end up being discarded because a lock already exists. Or, you might use an old runtime without `java.util.concurrent`. In cases like those you could synchronize on the map:

```
Object lock;
synchronized (locks) {
  if (locks.containsKey(key))
    lock = locks.get(key);
  else {
    lock = new Object();
    locks.put(key, object);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking, locking on the interned Strings just seemed like a really bad idea for some reason.  But in this scenario I am locking every call on the Map - but I guess this isn't that different (performance wise) then my cache which is shared by all the threads.  I would think even this overhead is still way faster then making multiple unneeded calls to my user authentication provider.

Answer (score 2):

> I've thought about locking on the String "Bob" (because due to interning it's always the same object right?). Would that work?

[I've previously tried this and it actually doesn't work quite like you might expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/problem-with-synchronizing-on-string-objects). You need to make sure you call `intern()` on the Strings first; however, synchronizing on intern strings is actually a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are caching with a Map, then locking on the key would do what you suggest.