# Locking on Strings

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

2 Questions:

1. str field is shared between two instance of A type [line 2]
2. What's implications according to following code ?

---

```
class A implements Runnable {
    String str = "hello"; // line 2.

    public void run(){
        Synchronized(str){
            System.out.println(str+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(100);
            System.out.println(str+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            //anything
        }
    }

    public void static main(String[] args){  
        Thread one = new Thread(new A(),"one").start();  
        Thread two = new Thread(new A(),"two").start();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronizing on String objects in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/synchronizing-on-string-objects-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The field itself *isn't* shared between two instances. They are distinct fields. However, they start off with the same value, as string literals are interned.

That means when the `synchronized` block acquires the string's monitor in one thread, it will prevent the other thread from acquiring the same monitor. It's important to understand that the `synchronized` block is acquiring the lock for the monitor associated with the *value* of the field - it doesn't matter that there are two separate fields involved.

Moral: don't synchronize on strings, particularly literals. Literals are particularly bad, because in this case you could have another class with the same code as `A`, and that would *also* try to synchronize using the same monitor.

Comment: you said `it doesn't matter that there are two separate fields` I think just in **immutable classes** case -- Right??

Comment: @MinelsMine: Not really - because it's only the values that matter. Who cares whether the field values *can* change if they never *do* actually change?

Comment: (And even if they do change, it's the value *at the point of lock acquisition* which is important.)

Answer (score 4):

Locking on strings in this manner can be dangerous. According to [Section 3.10.5 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Literal strings within different
>   classes in different packages likewise
>   represent references to the same
>   `String` object.

What this means is that if another class contains the same string literal, it will refer to the same `String` object and could result in a deadlock.

It would be better to use one of the explicit locks from the [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) package or even a `new Object()`.

Example:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
String str = "hello";    

public void run(){
    lock.lock(); 
    try{
        System.out.println(str+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(str+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    finally{
        lock.unlock();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! The JLS reference is helpful