# Java Thread Ping Pong example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to understand thread basics, and as a first example I create two thread that write a  String on the stdout. As I know the scheduler allows to execute the threads using a round robin schedule. Thats why I got:

> PING
>   PING
>   pong
>   pong
>   pong
>   PING
>   PING
>   PING
>   pong
>   pong

Now I want to use a shared variable, so every thread will know if its your turn:

```
public class PingPongThread extends Thread {
private String msg;
private static String turn;

public PingPongThread(String msg){
    this.msg = msg;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        playTurn();
    }

}
public synchronized void playTurn(){
    if (!msg.equals(turn)){
        turn=msg;
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
}
```

Main class:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PingPongThread thread1 = new PingPongThread("PING");
        PingPongThread thread2 = new PingPongThread("pong");
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

I synchronized the "turn manager" but I still get something like:

> PING
>   PING
>   pong
>   pong
>   pong
>   PING
>   PING
>   PING
>   pong
>   pong

**Can someone explains what I am missing, and Why I'm not getting Ping pong... ping pong**.
Thanks!

Comment: how is the turn manager implemented ?

Comment: By "turn manager" I mean public synchronized void playTurn()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This line:

```
public synchronized void playTurn(){
    //code
}
```

is equivalent in behavior to

```
public void playTurn() {
    synchronized(this) {
         //code
    }
}
```

that's why no synchronization is occuring, because as Brian Agnew pointed out, the threads are synchronizing on two different objects (thread1, thread2), each on it's own instance resulting in no effective synchronization.

If you would use your turn variable for synchronization, e.g.:

```
private static String turn = ""; // must initialize or you ll get an NPE

public void playTurn() {
    synchronized(turn) {
         //...
         turn = msg; // (1)
         //...
    }
}
```

then the situation is a lot better (run multiple times to verify), but there is also no 100% synchronization. In the beggining (mostly) you get a double ping and double pong, and afterwards they look synchronized, but you still can get double pings/pongs.

The synchronized block locks upon *value* (see this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984987/locking-on-strings)) and not the *reference to that value*. (see EDIT)

So let's take a look at one possible scenario:

```
thread1 locks on ""
thread2 blocks on ""
thread1 changes the value of turn variable to "PING" - thread2 can continue since "" is no longer locked
```

To verify that I tried putting

```
try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); // try with 10, 100 also multiple times
 } 
 catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

before and after

```
turn = msg;
```

and it looks synchronized?! But, if you put

```
 try {
    Thread.yield();
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); //  also  try multiple times
 } 
 catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
```

after few seconds you'll see double pings/pongs. [Thread.yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield()) essenitally means "I'm  done with the processor, put some else thread to work". This is obviously system thread scheduler implementation on my OS.

So, to synchronize correctly we must remove line

```
    turn = msg;
```

so that threads could always synchronize on the same value - not really :) As explained in the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984987/locking-on-strings) given above - Strings (immutable objects) are dangerous as locks - because if you create String "A" on 100 places in your program all 100 references(variables) will point to the same "A" in memory - so you could *oversynchronize*.

So, to answer your original question, modify your code like this:

```
 public void playTurn() {
    synchronized(PingPongThread.class) {
         //code
    }
}
```

and the parallel PingPong example will be 100% correctly implemented (see EDIT^2).

The above code is equivalent to:

```
 public static synchronized void playTurn() {
     //code
 }
```

The PingPongThread.class is a [Class object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html), e.g. on every instance you can call [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) which always has  only one instance.

Also you could do like this

```
 public static Object lock = new Object();

 public void playTurn() {
    synchronized(lock) {
         //code
    }
}
```

Also, read and program examples(running multiple times whenever neccessary) this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

EDIT:

To be [technically correct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#56318):

The synchronized method is the same as synchronized statement locking upon this. Let's call the argument of the synchronized statement "lock" - as Marko pointed out, "lock" is a variable storing a reference to an object/instance of a class. To quote the spec:

> The synchronized statement computes a reference to an object; it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor..

So the synchronizaton is not acutally made upon *value* - the object/class instance, but upon the *object monitor associated* with that instance/value. Because

> Each object in Java is associated with a monitor..

the effect remains the same.

EDIT^2:

Following up on the comments remarks:
"and the parallel PingPong example will be 100% correctly implemented" - meaning, the desired behavior is achieved (without error).

IMHO, a solution is correct if the result is correct. There are many ways of solving the problem, so the next criteria would be simplicity/elegance of the solution - the phaser solution is better approach, because as Marko said in other words in some comment there is a lot lesser chance of making error using phaser object than using synchronized mechanism - which can be seen from all the (non)solution variants in this post. Notable to see is also comparison of code size and overall clarity.

To conclude, this [sort of constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) should be used whenever they are applicable to the problem in question.

Comment: Kummo I strongly suggest to study the Phaser example - it is very elegant solution. [API doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)

Comment: This statement confuses me: "The synchronized block locks upon value of the variable and not the reference to that value." But the value of a variable *is a reference* and, indeed, each distinct reference value is associated with a unique monitor (of the unique object that particular value refers to).

Comment: Also, I would really hesitate to call a busy-waiting solution "correct". Even though it is correct in the narrow technical sense, calling it that without qualification is not exactly educational.

Comment: The Java terminology (e.g. pointer/reference saga) is confusing :) I updated as suggested, pls verify. I don't understand what do you mean by "without qualification" - please explain and Ill gladly update the post accordingly

Comment: I think I understood what you ment by "...without qualification is not exactly educational". Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Don't lock on String constants since the string gets interned and two threads that should be using different monitors might actually be using the same one.

Answer (score 13):

In conclusion to my discussion with Brian Agnew, I submit this code that uses `java.util.concurrent.Phaser` to coordinate your ping-pong threads:

```
static final Phaser p = new Phaser(1);
public static void main(String[] args) {
  t("ping");
  t("pong");
}
private static void t(final String msg) {
  new Thread() { public void run() {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println(msg);
      p.awaitAdvance(p.arrive()+1);
    }
  }}.start();
}
```

The key difference between this solution and the one you attempted to code is that your solution busy-checks a flag, thereby wasting CPU time (and energy!). The correct approach is to use blocking methods that put a thread to sleep until it is notified of the relevant event.

Answer (score 4):

Each instance of the `PingPongThread` is synchronising on itself and *not* on a shared resource. In order to control the message passing you'll need to synchronise on a shared resource (e.g. your `turn` variable ?)

However I don't think this is really going to work. I think you should check out `wait()` and `notify()` to do this (if you want to understand the threading primitives). See [this](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/concurrency/ping-pong.jspx) for an example.

Comment: Better suggest a `java.util.concurrent` synchronizer, such as `Phaser` or `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: @Marko - I was wondering about that. If the aim is to understand the threading primitives, then I stand by the above. However I would certainly advocate your approach for 'production' type code!

Comment: New Java users simply shouldn't be exposed to `wait` and `notify`, except under the category "advanced programming". This a very raw mechanism resulting in either wrong usage or much boilerplate to implement it right. That just sidetracks learners.

Comment: Note the OP's comment about trying to understand thread basics. However, my other thought was to go in completely the opposite direction and suggest an Actor framework (e.g. Akka). After all, that's the perfect abstraction here

Comment: I just feel that the basics don't always mean "how it's implemented down below", otherwise everyone should start learning Java by first learning CPU architecture, assembler, and C. I agree with your point with Akka (my example in that direction would be the Executor Framework). These tools abstract away the whole concept of threads, but they get the job done the proper way. Synchronizers are the "middle ground" here, basically they just encapsulate the correct wait-notify idioms in a foolproof package.

Comment: It really is questionable whether the user, as a first lesson, should learn about spurious wakeups and wait sets. In fact, it would be best for most Java users if they never needed to get to the bottom of these low-level artifacts. They are in almost the same category as JNI, for example, or the `Unsafe` class.

Comment: It makes me real angry and sad that gentlemen with such great knowledge (and skyrocket rep), first, don't *actually* answer the question to someone who *wants to learn and understand*, and secondly, the only advice to his *original* question is actually wrong and then continue with (very interesting and valuable) discussion which *cant help him much* (at this point). As to the discussion - if we were talking about learnign programming (paradigms) I would 100% agree. But threading *is* actually about assembler(where C,Java primitives are just a more readable form) and must be understood at...

Comment: the level they exist - which is the primitive level. Upon understanding that I would agree to move on the concepts you described. It would be like learning to integrate before you know how to add.

Comment: @linski Do you also propose that everyone must understand the notions of the *p-n* barrier, Fermi distribution, conduction bands, CMOS transistors, etc, before daring to code in assembler?

Comment: LoL, of course not. But if you want to make your own homemade remote control, then you should know something about that, no? I suppose that we agree that you must understand the problem before you can succesfully program it. And in this example also, you must contemplate the execution of the code *line by line* which is what happens at machine code level - and no I don't think you should program in binary code nor asm, but at first more readable interpretation which is close enough. To correct myself I'would agree that it need not be the *very first*..

Comment: but I think it must be amongst the beggining examples. Actually I thought that in the first comment but expressed myself wrongly, sorry about that.

Comment: @linski It should be more than enough to understand your code at the level of the contract of the APIs/language features you use. So if you use `Phaser`, as I propose, there will be no need to get involved with wait/notify. Understanding `Phaser` is quite a bit simpler -- and more empowering -- than wasting time on understanding and debugging wait/notify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17717/discussion-between-linski-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this :

```
public class InfinitePingPong extends Thread  {

    private static final Object lock= new Object();

private String toPrintOut;

    public InfinitePingPong(String s){
        this.toPrintOut = s;
    }


    public void run(){
        while (true){
            synchronized(lock){
                System.out.println(this.toPrintOut +" -->"+this.getId()); 
                lock.notifyAll();

                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        InfinitePingPong a = new InfinitePingPong("ping");
        InfinitePingPong b = new InfinitePingPong("pong");


        a.start();
        b.start();

        b.wait();

        try {
            a.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }








}
}
```

Comment: Just wonder, how could you be sure both a and b wont do several loops before b.wait() is called?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using SynchronousQueue .

```
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;

public class PingPongPattern {

    private SynchronousQueue<Integer> q = new SynchronousQueue<Integer>();
    private Thread t1 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try {

                    System.out.println("Ping");
                    q.put(1);
                    q.put(2);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }

    };

    private Thread t2 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.run();
                try {
                    q.take();
                    System.out.println("Pong");
                    q.take();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }

        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PingPongPattern p = new PingPongPattern();
        p.t1.start();
        p.t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ping Pong program written in Java. Ping and Pong are separate threads. Each thread is both a consumer and a producer. When each thread runs it does two things

1. Produce a message that allows the other (as a consumer) to run
2. Consume a message that causes itself to suspend.

The code is based upon Oracles ProducerConsumerExample. Note that the Ping and  Pong classes are almost identical in their code and in their behaviour. 
The threads in the OP’s code only uses the ‘mutual exclusion’ part of the objects monitor (as Brian Agnew suggested above). They never invoke a wait. Hence they only exclude one another, but never invoke the java run time to allow the other thread to run.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

 * based on oracle example on sync-wait-notify
 * cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html
 * run with java ProducerConsumerExample
 * 
 *
 */ 

public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drop drop = new Drop();
    DropCtoP dropCtoP = new DropCtoP();
    (new Thread(new Ping(drop,dropCtoP))).start();
        (new Thread(new Pong(drop,dropCtoP))).start();
    }
}


public class Pong implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;
    private DropCtoP dropCtoP;
    private int count=0;

    public Pong(Drop drop,DropCtoP dropCtoP) {
        this.drop = drop;
        this.dropCtoP = dropCtoP;
    }

    public void run() {
        String message;
        for (;;) {
        count++;
            message = drop.take();
            System.out.format("Pong running - : %s - ran num times %d %n", message,count);
            dropCtoP.put("Run ping token");
        }
    }
}



public class Ping implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;
    private DropCtoP dropCtoP;
    private int count=0;

    public Ping(Drop drop,DropCtoP dropCtoP) {
        this.drop = drop;
        this.dropCtoP = dropCtoP;
    }

    public void run() {

        String message;
        for (;;) {
      count++;
      drop.put("Run pong token");
      message = dropCtoP.take();
      System.out.format("PING running - : %s- ran num times %d %n", message,count);
        }

    }
}



public class DropCtoP {
    // Message sent from producer
    // to consumer.
    private String message;
    // True if consumer should wait
    // for producer to send message,
    // false if producer should wait for
    // consumer to retrieve message.
    private boolean empty2 = true;


    public synchronized String take() {
        // Wait until message is
        // available.
        while (empty2) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty2 = true;
        // Notify producer that
        // status has changed.
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Wait until message has
        // been retrieved.
        while (!empty2) {
            try { 
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty2 = false;
        // Store message.
        this.message = message;
        // Notify consumer that status
        // has changed.
        notifyAll();
    }    
}


public class Drop {
    // Message sent from producer
    // to consumer.
    private String message;
    // True if consumer should wait
    // for producer to send message,
    // false if producer should wait for
    // consumer to retrieve message.
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String take() {
        // Wait until message is
        // available.
        while (empty) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = true;
        // Notify producer that
        // status has changed.
        notifyAll();
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Wait until message has
        // been retrieved.
        while (!empty) {
            try { 
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        // Toggle status.
        empty = false;
        // Store message.
        this.message = message;
        // Notify consumer that status
        // has changed.
        notifyAll();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible implementations:

```
public class PingPongDemo {

    private static final int THREADS = 2;

    private static int nextIndex = 0;

    private static String getMessage(int index) {
        return index % 2 == 0 ? "ping" : "pong";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        var lock = new ReentrantLock();

        var conditions = new Condition[THREADS];
        for (int i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
            conditions[i] = lock.newCondition();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
            var index = i;

            new Thread(() -> {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println(getMessage(index));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                        nextIndex = (nextIndex + 1) % THREADS;

                        conditions[nextIndex].signal();

                        while (nextIndex != index) {
                            conditions[index].awaitUninterruptibly();
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }).start();

            if (index < THREADS - 1) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (nextIndex != (index + 1)) {
                        conditions[index + 1].awaitUninterruptibly();
                    }
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here, we're effectively making round-robin output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses `Semaphore` objects to accomplish synchronization:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Main {
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface QuadFunction<T, U, V, W, R> {
        public R apply(T t, U u, V v, W w);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Terminating...");
            svc.shutdownNow();
            try { svc.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {};
        }));

        var sem1 = new Semaphore(1);
        var sem2 = new Semaphore(0);

        QuadFunction<String, String, Semaphore, Semaphore, Runnable> fun =
            (name, action, s1, s2) ->
                (Runnable) () -> {
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            s1.acquire();
                            System.out.format("%s %s\n", name, action);
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                            s2.release(1);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    s2.release(1);
                    System.out.format("==> %s shutdown\n", name);
                };

        svc.execute(fun.apply("T1", "ping", sem1, sem2));
        svc.execute(fun.apply("T2", "pong", sem2, sem1));
    }
}
```