# Asynchronous (non-blocking) version of synchronized(){}

Tags: java, akka, vert.x

Is there a good way to implement an asynchronous version of synchronized keyword? Obviously the synchronized() keyword will frequently block the current thread. For example:

```
  public static boolean getLockSync(Runnable r) {

    if (isLocked) {
      r.run();
      return true;
    }

    synchronized (My.lock) { // this is blocking, could block for more than 1-2 ms
      isLocked = true;
      r.run();
      isLocked = false;
      return false;
    }

  }
```

I can return a boolean from this block - it's synchronous. Is there a way to do this asynchronously?

Something like this:

```
  public static void getLockAsync(Runnable r) {

    if (isLocked) {
      CompletableFuture.runAsync(r);
      return;
    }

    Object.onLockAcquisition(My.lock, () -> { // this is non-blocking
           isLocked = true;
           r.run();
           isLocked = false;
           Object.releaseLock(My.lock);
     });

  }
```

I made up the Object.onLockAcquisition method, but looking for something like that.

Comment: No and why would you do/want that? Your `if(isLocked)` is also unsafe.

Comment: if(isLocked) is atomic, it's fine. Ever worked in a non-blocking environment?

Comment: Yes and internally it actually uses low level blocking. When if its atomic, its safe only to check the value itself. Nothing guarantees that it won't become false between your check and the moment you enter the next line - the `r.run()` call.

Comment: @Fureeish when the onLockAcquisition callback fires, you have obtained the lock - it's analogous to entering a synchronized{} block..

Comment: Where did I mention `Object.onLockAcquisition`? I was referring to the very first if statemenents in your getLock methods.

Comment: `isLocked` doesn't look atomic to me. You're updating it while holding a lock but reading it without holding that same lock.

Comment: This question might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457146/is-there-a-way-to-synchronize-on-string-variable-in-java-apart-from-using-intern

Comment: Even if your made-up `Object.onLockAcquisition` did the right thing, you are still executing the runnable without it if `isLocked` happened to be `true` the very moment before you call `CompletableFuture.runAsync(r);`, which breaks the entire construct.

Comment: @Holger it really doesn't - in order to write the boolean you need the lock, but to read from it you don't.

Comment: So what feature does your construct actually provide? The tasks may run without holding the lock, the value of the boolean variable may change an arbitrary number of times while running, hence is entirely meaningless, so what's the point of it?

Comment: What's the semantic of the async lock acquisition supposed to be?

Comment: Dont worry about the semantics - the only semantics that matter are blocking vs. non-blocking...the synchronized keyword is a blocking call as usual.

Comment: So you are asking for a construct that has no useful effect? Just remove the `synchronized` without any replacement and you get what you are asking for. Unless you describe anything meaningful besides saying "non-blocking".

Answer (score 6):

Have you investigated alternatives? Depending what you're trying to achieve then one - or a combination - of the following might help (or not):

- double locking alternatives (using volatile + monitor and check the volatile twice, once before locking, once after locking)
- use AtomicXXX and there compareAndSet/compareAndExchange etc.. methods
- use the java.util.concurrent.locks
- use a single threaded executor to execute the critical section
- use a queue

Comment: ok, i agree with some of these, but since this is a somewhat common use case I was hoping there was a library that handles this already. Single threaded executor wont quite work in my case, but yes thats a good technique.

Comment: Single-threaded executor won't solve it by itself, because the current thread will block until it has access to the thread in the pool. Ultimately non-blocking locks need a special implementation. Non-blocking locks would most likely use a queue, that's right.

Comment: Can you show an example of how java.util.concurrent.locks might be used to implement a non-blocking lock on an Object's monitor or just a string key?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Right - java.util.concurrent.locks don't support directly the functionality you're looking for. But unlike monitors they allow you to test whether a lock is locked, or attempt to acquire the lock within a given delay.

Answer (score 6):

The correct solution in terms of Vert.x would be to use `SharedData.getLock()`
Reason for that is that asynchronicity is part of a specific library, and not of JVM platform.

Unless Vert.x runs in a clustered mode, it will fall back to local lock:

```
public void getLockWithTimeout(String name, long timeout, Handler<AsyncResult<Lock>> resultHandler) {
    ...
    if (clusterManager == null) {
      getLocalLock(name, timeout, resultHandler);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
```

`getLock` uses `LocalAsyncLocal` underneath:

```
localAsyncLocks.acquire(vertx.getOrCreateContext(), name, timeout, resultHandler);
```

`acquire()` uses `ConcurrentHashMap.compute` under the hood:
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/shareddata/impl/LocalAsyncLocks.java#L91

So if you really want to have your own implementation, you can take inspiration from the code above.

Comment: will prob accept this when the bounty period ends but gonna see if anyone comes up with alternatives

Comment: Yeah I think it would be a good idea to have a implementation for this in vert.x, something async that also plays nicely with the synchronized keyword too

Comment: `synchronized` plays on a different level than asynchronous frameworks, so I'm not sure it will work out.

Comment: yes after more reading, I agree, wait() and notify() are for threads, and wait() will block and notify will wake up another thread - those won't work I agree

Comment: Unless we are guaranteed a single-threaded environment without pre-emption, I don't think there is a way to avoid using synchronized(){}, because we'd need to synchronize access to the locking library across threads obviously, so kinda back to square one.

Answer (score 5):

One solution in Vertx is the toolkit's asynchronous locking calls:

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_asynchronous_locks

which looks like:

```
sd.getLock("mylock", res -> {
   Lock lock = res.result();
   vertx.setTimer(5000, tid -> lock.release());
});
```

however, this is *not* really the solution I am looking for, as this is a networked lock, which means it's pretty slow compared to a normal in-memory lock. I only need to create a lock in a single thread not across threads or processes.

Comment: Obtaining lock per thread doesn't make much sense in Vert.x, since your code may be executed on different threads.

Comment: @Alexey Soshin, I disagree..Java is generally a multithreaded environment, we have locking in a single thread all the time, that is in fact what `synchronized()` is for..

Comment: That's if you own the thread. But Vert.x is using event loop for asynchronicity. Do you really want to lock the event loop? Probably not.

Comment: yeah sorry I mispoke, all the locks i am looking for will lock on an object in memory. what i meant is i dont want a networked lock, i just want an in memory lock

Comment: See my answer below. Unless you run in cluster mode, your lock will be an in-memory lock.

Comment: yeah i saw that, i guess i am looking for an exposed part of the getLocalLock API - I never want a networked lock even if in clustered mode