# Synchronize access to given key in a ConcurrentMap

Tags: java, guava

I often enough want to access (and possibly add/remove) elements of a given `ConcurrentMap` so that only one thread can access any single key at a time. What is the best way to do this? Synchronizing on the key itself doesn't work: other threads might access the same key via an `equal` instance.

It's good enough if the answer only works with the maps built by [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `MapMaker`.

Comment: Indeed I'm wondering why Maps don't have method `getKey(key)` which returns key instance.

Comment: Are you saying you want to synchronise access within the `ConcurrentMap` during lookups (which doesn't quite make sense to me) or after the fact, once the value has been sourced from the map?

Comment: @JustYo if you have an equal key instance, why would you need the instance in the map? If that key would be mutable I'd doubt the design choice to use that key here.

Comment: @Thomas having such method will solve task of synchronizing by key. That won't work with equal but different instance.

Comment: Try with using Hashtable

Comment: @JustYo So why would one want to synchronize on the key? I can think of 2 situations: 1. prevent concurrent access to the value -> synchronize on the value. 2. the value might be changed/replaced causing a "dirty read" like situation -> add a level of indirection (e.g. a value holder) and synchronize on that.

Comment: @Thomas Option 2 won't help when you want to remove the value instead of replacing it. Of course, it's possible to add an "empty" state to the value holder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See a simple solution here [Simple Java name based locks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639870/simple-java-name-based-locks/5640671#5640671)

EDIT: This solution has a clear happens-before relation from unlock to lock. However, the next solution, now withdrawn, doesn't. The `ConcurrentMap` javadoc is too light to guaranteed that.

---

(*Withdrawn*) If you want to reuse your map as a lock pool,

```
private final V LOCK = ...; // a fake value
// if a key is mapped to LOCK, that means the key is locked
ConcurrentMap<K,V> map = ...;

V lock(key)
    V value;  
    while( (value=map.putIfAbsent(key, LOCK))==LOCK )
        // another thread locked it before me
        wait();
    // now putIfAbsent() returns a real value, or null
    // and I just sucessfully put LOCK in it
    // I am now the lock owner of this key
    return value; // for caller to work on

// only the lock owner of the key should call this method
unlock(key, value)
    // I put a LOCK on the key to stall others
    // now I just need to swap it back with the real value
    if(value!=null) 
        map.put(key, value);
    else // map doesn't accept null value
        map.remove(key)
    notifyAll();

test()
    V value = lock(key);

    // work on value

    // unlock. 
    // we have a chance to specify a new value here for the next worker
    newValue = ...; // null if we want to remove the key from map
    unlock(key, newValue); // in finally{}
```

This is quite messy because we reuse the map for two difference purposes. It's better to have lock pool as a separate data structure, leave map simply as the k-v storage.

Comment: I prefer sjr's answer to the linked question to the accepted one.

Comment: Why? Of course, values need to be weak, so if nobody needs a lock right now, entries will be evicted from the lock map.

Comment: you still have the key->weakReference entry in the map

Comment: "it is possible for a key or value present in the the map to be reclaimed by the garbage collector. _If this happens, the entry automatically disappears from the map._" If I don't have a reference to the key any longer, I certainly won't have a reference to the value (which is only accessed through the map) and the corresponding entry will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I see. I was not familiar with MapMaker. But if the lock object can disappear then get recreated, different threads may `synchronize` on different objects, and happens-before relation may not hold

Comment: `makeComputingMap` ensures that when several threads try to create a value for a key which doesn't exist in the map, only one value is created. And of course, the lock can only disappear while nobody is synchronizing on it.

Comment: The problem is happens-before relation from unlock action to next lock action. with `synchronized(getLock(key)){...}`, if returned lock changes, we'll have visibility issues. This prompts me to reexamine my solution with ConcurrentMap. Too bad the javadoc of it just doesn't make enough guarantees so that my unlock-lock has happens-before relation. Neither is ConcurrentHashMap. We could dig into the implementation to argue about synchronization behaviors; but just based on public javadoc, my solution cannot guarantee happens-before, so I have to withdraw it too.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private static final Set<String> lockedKeys = new HashSet<>();

    private void lock(String key) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lockedKeys) {
            while (!lockedKeys.add(key)) {
                lockedKeys.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    private void unlock(String key) {
        synchronized (lockedKeys) {
            lockedKeys.remove(key);
            lockedKeys.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void doSynchronouslyOnlyForEqualKeys(String key) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            lock(key);

            //Put your code here.
            //For different keys it is executed in parallel.
            //For equal keys it is executed synchronously.

        } finally {
            unlock(key);
        }
    }
```

- **key** can be not only a 'String' but any class with correctly overridden 'equals' and 'hashCode' methods.
- **try-finally** - is very important - you must guarantee to unlock waiting threads after your operation even if your operation threw exception.
- It will not work if your back-end is distributed across **multiple servers/JVMs**.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create you own class that extends concurrentmap.
Override the `get(Object key)` method, so it checks if the requested key object is already 'checked out' by another thread ?

You'll also have to make a new method in your concurrentmap that 'returns' the items to the map, so they are available again to another thread.