# Synchronize on value, not object

Tags: java, thread-safety, synchronized

I want to do something like this in Java

```
  public void giveMoney(String userId, int money) {
    synchronized (userId) {

        Profile p = fetchProfileFromDB(userId);
        p.setMoney(p.getMoney() + userId);
        saveProfileToDB(p);

    }
   }
```

But of course, synchronizing on a string is not correct. What's a correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't synchronise on the `Profile`?

Comment: I'm interested in finding out why synchronizing on a string is not correct..

Comment: @Jim It is newly created for every request.

Comment: @mrkhrts `synchronized` uses the object identity. There can be multiple copies of a string with different identities but the same contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the set of user ids is limited, you can synchronize on an interned version of the `String`.

Either use `String.intern()` (which has a few drawbacks) or something like Guava [`Interners`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Interners.html) if you need a bit more control over the interning.

Comment: We have a about 200k users, and expect many more, so it's not really limited. Also see my comment on stevevis about `intern`

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: a custom `Interner` can work around *both* of those problems: since you have a *custom* interner, you don't run the risk of colliding with other code.

Comment: Would a simple `Interners.<String>newWeakInterner()` do what I want?

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: I think it would.

Comment: Great, that's simple and easy :)

Comment: why is it bad to use string intern?

Comment: @gaurav depending on your JVM implementation and version it might put the Strings into the perm gen and prevent them from ever being collected.

Comment: @JoachimSauer true...but if my JVM implementation prevent them from GC, then the code will provide synchronization on accurate object?

Comment: @gaurav yes, synchronisation on interned strings should always work correctly, it's just that interning might have unintended side effects.

Comment: unintended side effects such as?

Answer (score 5):

In principle, you can synchronize on any object in Java. It's not in itself "not correct" to synchronize on a `String` object; it depends on what exactly you're doing.

But if `userId` is a local variable in a method, then this is not going to work. Each thread that executes the method with have its own copy of the variable (presumably referring to a different `String` object for each thread); synchronizing between threads ofcourse only works when you make multiple threads synchronize on the same object.

You'd have to make the object you're synchronizing on a member variable of the object that contains the method in which you have the `synchronized` block. If multiple threads are then calling the method on the same object, you'll achieve mutual exclusivity.

```
class Something {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void someMethod() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use explicit locks from the `java.util.concurrent.locks` package, that can give you more control if you need that:

```
class Something {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void someMethod() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Especially if you want an exclusive lock for writing, but you don't want threads to have to wait for each other when reading, you might want to use a `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was referring to in my answer, although I wasn't as elegant.

Comment: Yes, your second paragraph explains why I call it incorrect.

Comment: Regarding your expansion, yes, I could lock every time I update anybody's money, which would definitely work as a second-best solution. That doesn't allow me to update multiple users in parallel though.

Comment: If this is all about doing atomic database updates (fetch, update, store), then you should use database transactions and let the database handle the locking of rows.

Comment: @Jesper It is, and I know, but the database doesn't currently support it and it's not mine.

Comment: @Jesper: Your comment is generally true, but does not solve @BartvanHeukelom problem: he needs to associate a unique user with a lock. The simple solution will be to maintain `String -> Object` map with user as a key, and any object as a lock or to use solution proposed by @irreputable.

Comment: @dma_k I know, and the answer by Joachim that Bart accepted also works well.

Answer (score 4):

I guess there are a few options.

The easiest is that you could map a `userId` to a lock object in a threadsafe map. Others have mentioned interning but I don't think that's a viable option.

However, the more common option would be to synchronize on `p` (the Profile).  This is appropriate if `getProfile()` is threadsafe, and by its name I would suspect it might be.

Comment: The problem with the profile is that a new instance is created for every request. I'll clarify the sample code a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically speaking, since interned objects can be GC-ed, it's possible to synchronized on different objects (of the same value) at different times. Mutual exclusivity is still guaranteed, since it's not possible to synchronized on different objects at the *same* time.

However, if we synchronized on different objects, the happens-before relation is at doubt. We have to examine the implementation to find out. And since it involves GC, which Java Memory Model does not address, the reasoning can be quite difficult.

That's a theoretical objection; practically I don't think it'll cause any problem.

Still, there can be simple, direct, and theoretically correct solution to your problem. For example [Simple Java name based locks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639870/simple-java-name-based-locks/5640671#5640671)

Comment: I don't mind if the interned IDs are GC'd, as long as the mutual exclusivity is guaranteed. In fact I want them to be GC'd, because there'll be many different IDs. Thanks for the link, it's also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proxy object for the string.

```
Object userIdMutex = new Object();

synchronized (userIdMutex) {
    Profile p = getProfile(userId);
    p.setMoney(p.getMoney() + p);
    saveProfile(p);
}
```

Use this mutex whenever you access `userId`.

Comment: But where could I get the object? If I would create a new one for every request as in your example there is no actual locking.

Comment: It would be a static field of the class.

Comment: `userIdMutex` must ofcourse not be a local variable, because it won't work if you do that.

Comment: "It would be a static field of the class." - It would be nice if your sample code showed that detail ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I assume you want to obtain a lock to a profile class, change it, and then release the lock. Synchronization is not exactly what you need in my opinion. You need a class that manages those records and lets you lock and unlock a record when changes need to be made to it, aka source control style.

Check this out: [Lock class Java 5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)

Answer (score -4):

What about this:

```
String userId = ...;
Object userIdLock = new Object();
synchronized (userIdLock) {
    Profile p = getProfile(userId);
    p.setMoney(p.getMoney() + p);
    saveProfile(p);
}
```

It's simple and above all **obvious**.

Comment: How does that give you mutual exclusivity?

Comment: Wow ... that's ... apropos your name. If `userIdLock` is "escaping" outside the local variable, then that `synchronized` block is *entirely useless*.

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @mrkhrts Each thread calling this code will have it's own Object, and thus it's own lock.

Comment: @Jim, Not if it's a field of the class, correct?

Comment: Of course you must share lock object between threads. How you will do it depends on way you want to lock.

Comment: @mrkhrts: if it's a field, then the `userIdLock` object will be independent of the `userId` value and thus everyone will synchronize on a single huge lock, which is A Bad Thing™ for multi-threaded performance.

Comment: Well i maybe misunderstood point of that question :/