# Synchronize on resource item. i.e. lock on ID; in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have the following methods:

```
public void create(Deploy deploy)
public void update(Deploy deploy)
```

These two methods work with same resource type, `Deploy`. I would like to synchronize these two methods, as creating and updating is non-atomic. However, synchronizing methods is too much - I do not want to block access on two different `deployId`. Users should be able to create two deploys with different `deployId` in the same time.

What would be the best way to achieve this in Java8? I was thinking in having (weak?) hashmap of used IDs and have lock on them; something like:

```
String id = deploy.getId();
lockMap.lockWith(id);  // lookup for Lock and creates if missing
...//work
lockMap.release(id)
```

Is there anything better then this? I guess there is ;)

Comment: I suppose you need some kind of lock stripping. Look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124539/how-to-acquire-a-lock-by-a-key, http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347825/704335 http://stackoverflow.com/a/28347825/704335