# Why is it "dangerous" to synchronize on method parameter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

My IDE (JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA) warns me about synchronizing on a method parameter even when it's always an object.

[image]

The full warning reads:

> Synchronization on method parameter 's' ... Inspection
>   info: Reports synchronization on a local variable or parameter. It is
>   very difficult to guarantee correctness when such synchronization is
>   used. It may be possible to improve code like this by controlling
>   access through e.g. a synchronized wrapper class, or by synchronizing
>   on a field.

My guess is that with auto-boxing, the parameter might be a primitive which gets converted to an object? Although, with auto-boxing, I would assume it's always an object, but maybe not a shared object which means it wouldn't be shared synchronization.

Anyone know why the warning would be present? In my case `ShortCircuit` type is always an object and the IDE should be able to know that.

Answer (score 12):

The thing is that if you forget to synchronize on `ShortCircuit` when using it in other places of your code you might get unpredictable results. It's a lot better to synchronize inside the `ShortCircuit` class so it's guaranteed to be thread safe.

**Update**

If you're moving the synchronization outside of the class it's inherently unsafe for threading. If you want to synchronize on it externally you will have to audit all places it's used, that's why you get the warning. It's all about good encapsulation. It will be even worse if it is in a public API.

Now if you move the `fireFinalCallback` method to your `ShortCircuit` class you can guarantee that the callback won't fire simultaneously. Otherwise you need to have this in mind when calling the methods on that class.

Comment: @AlexanderMills updated the answer. It's hard to give an example since it's more about encapsulation than a short example can show.

Comment: I twitched inside when I read "undefined behaviour". While this is true, given a sufficiently broad interpretation of the term, "undefined behaviour" is a term that has such strong (and disastrous!) implications in languages like C++ that I'd rather talk about "unpredictable results" or "unspecified results" or something similar.

Answer (score 7):

As [jontro already mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775191/3182664) (and basically, as the warning already says) : This sort of synchronization on the `ShortCircuit` object does not have the effect that the developer probably hoped to achieve. Unfortunately, the tooltip in your screenshot hides the actual code, but it seems like the code could roughly be

```
synchronized (s)
{
    if (!s.isFinalCallbackFired())
    {
        s.doFire();
    }
}
```

That is: It is first checked whether `isFinalCallbackFired` returns `false`, and if this is the case, something (hidden) is done, which likely causes the `isFinalCallbackFired` state to switch to `true`.

So my assumption is, roughly, that the goal of putting the `if` statement into the `synchronized` block was to make sure that `doFire` is always called exactly **once**.

---

And indeed, at this point, the synchronization could be justified. More specifically, and a bit oversimplified:

What **can** be guaranteed:

When two threads are executing the `fireFinalCallback` method with the same `ShortCircuit` parameter, the `synchronized` block will guarantee that only *one* thread at a time can check the `isFinalCallbackFired` state and (if it is `false`) call the `doFire` method. So it is guaranteed that `doFire` will be called only *once*.

What **can not** be guaranteed:

When one thread is executing the `fireFinalCallback` method, and another thread does any operation on the `ShortCircuit` object (like calling `doFire`), then this might lead to an inconsistent state. Particularly, if another thread also does

```
if (!s.isFinalCallbackFired())
{
    s.doFire();
}
```

but *without* synchronizing on the object, then `doFire` may be called twice.

---

The following is an MCVE that illustrates the effect:

```
public class SynchronizeOnParameter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Running test without synchronization:");
        runWithoutSync();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Running test with synchronization:");
        runWithSync();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Running test with wrong synchronization:");
        runWithSyncWrong();
        System.out.println();

    }

    private static void runWithoutSync()
    {
        ShortCircuit s = new ShortCircuit();
        new Thread(() -> fireFinalCallbackWithoutSync(s)).start();
        pause(250);
        new Thread(() -> fireFinalCallbackWithoutSync(s)).start();
        pause(1000);
    }

    private static void runWithSync()
    {
        ShortCircuit s = new ShortCircuit();
        new Thread(() -> fireFinalCallbackWithSync(s)).start();
        pause(250);
        new Thread(() -> fireFinalCallbackWithSync(s)).start();
        pause(1000);
    }

    private static void runWithSyncWrong()
    {
        ShortCircuit s = new ShortCircuit();
        new Thread(() -> fireFinalCallbackWithSync(s)).start();

        if (!s.isFinalCallbackFired())
        {
            s.doFire();
        }
    }



    private static void fireFinalCallbackWithoutSync(ShortCircuit s)
    {
        if (!s.isFinalCallbackFired())
        {
            s.doFire();
        }
    }

    private static void fireFinalCallbackWithSync(ShortCircuit s)
    {
        synchronized (s)
        {
            if (!s.isFinalCallbackFired())
            {
                s.doFire();
            }
        }
    }

    static class ShortCircuit
    {
        private boolean fired = false;

        boolean isFinalCallbackFired()
        {
            return fired;
        }

        void doFire()
        {
            System.out.println("Calling doFire");
            pause(500);
            fired = true;
        }
    }

    private static void pause(long ms)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output is

```
Running test without synchronization:
Calling doFire
Calling doFire

Running test with synchronization:
Calling doFire

Running test with wrong synchronization:
Calling doFire
Calling doFire
```

So the `synchonized` block *does* make sure that the `doFire` method is only called once. But this only works if all modifications are only done in the `fureFinalCallback` method. If the object is modified elsewhere, without a `synchronized` block, the `doFire` method may be called twice.

(I'd like to offer a solution for this, but without details about the `ShortCircuit` class and the remaining classes and processes, one could only give the vague hint to have a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package and its subpackages: Locks and Conditions might be a viable path, but you have to figure that out...)