# Java: Synchronization based on object value

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, synchronization, thread-safety

I want to synchronize one method or one block based on input parameters.

So I have one API which has two inputs (let's say id1 and id2) of long type (could be primitive or wrapper)  in post payload, which can be JSON. This API will be called by multiple threads at the same time or at different times randomly.

Now if the first API call has id1=1 and id2=1, and at the same time another API call has id1=1 and id2=1, it should wait for the first API call to finish processing before executing the second call. If the second API call has a different combination of values like id1=1 and id2=2, it should go through parallel without any wait time.

I don't mind creating a service method also which the API resource method can call, rather than handling directly at API resource method.

I'm using Spring boot Rest Controlller APIs.

**Edit**
I've already tried using map as suggested but this partially works. It waits for all input values, not just the same input values. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    AccountResource ar = context.getBean(AccountResource.class);
    UID uid1 = new UID();
    uid1.setFieldId(1);
    uid1.setLetterFieldId(1);
    UID uid2 = new UID();
    uid2.setFieldId(2);
    uid2.setLetterFieldId(2);
    UID uid3 = new UID();
    uid3.setFieldId(1);
    uid3.setLetterFieldId(1);
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                ar.test(uid1);
            }

        }
    };
    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                ar.test(uid2);
            }

        }
    };
    Runnable r3 = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                ar.test(uid3);
            }

        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.start();
    Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
    t3.start();

}
@Path("v1/account")
@Service
public class AccountResource {
public void test(UID uid) {
        uidFieldValidator.setUid(uid);
        Object lock;
        synchronized (map) {
            lock = map.get(uid);
            if (lock == null) {
                map.put(uid, (lock = new Object()));
            }
            synchronized (lock) {
                //some operation
            }
        }
    }
}

package com.urman.hibernate.test;

import java.util.Objects;

public class UID {
    
    private long letterFieldId;
    private long fieldId;
    private String value;
    public long getLetterFieldId() {
        return letterFieldId;
    }
    public void setLetterFieldId(long letterFieldId) {
        this.letterFieldId = letterFieldId;
    }
    public long getFieldId() {
        return fieldId;
    }
    public void setFieldId(long fieldId) {
        this.fieldId = fieldId;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fieldId, letterFieldId);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        UID other = (UID) obj;
        return fieldId == other.fieldId && letterFieldId == other.letterFieldId;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're synchronized on the map as well as the lock object.  Look at the scope of your sync blocks compared to mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775142/why-is-it-dangerous-to-synchronize-on-method-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a collection of locks, which you can keep in a map and allocate as required. Here I assume that your id1 and id2 are Strings; adjust as appropriate.

```
 Map<String,Object> lockMap = new HashMap<>();
   :

 void someMethod(String id1, String id2) {
     Object lock;
     synchronized (lockMap) {
         lock = lockMap.get(id1+id2);
         if (lock == null) lockMap.put(id1+id2, (lock = new Object()));
     }
     synchronized (lock) {
         :
     }
 }
```

You need a little bit of 'global' synchronization for the map operations, or you could use one of the concurrent implementations. I used the base HashMap for simplicity of implementation.

After you've selected a lock, sync on it.

Comment: I have already tried this, I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: That's because you're synchronized on the map as well as the lock object.  Look at the scope of your sync blocks compared to mine.

Comment: lock = lockMap.get(id1+id2);
         if (lock == null) lockMap.put(id1+id2, (lock = new Object())); you can reduce to one line with computeifabsernt

Comment: @user15187356 , so this was working fine infact. Problem was with the Key of the Map that I was using. My hashCode and Equals method for UID class seems fine but still somehow, it is storing duplicate keys in the map and hence different object for each of that key, because of that lock was not working perfectly for the said object. This one with the HashMap key is weird issue actually. So as of now what I did is (And it is working fine) I used map of <String, Object> where key string will be something like letterfieldId+"`"+fieldId

Comment: @dreamcrash, thanks for the suggestion, I have changed it.

Comment: user15187356, not the best of answers. You can just sleep if you know the application scalability by doing Load testing.