# Syncronize method call on parameter value in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to synchronize this method on `id` argument value.
I was thinking about using string pool reference, is there a better way?

```
static void f(Number id) {
  String s = String.valueOf(id).intern();
  synchronized (s) {
   // syncronize this block by id value
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't do *that*. If you have Guava, you can use [StripedLock](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) for a nicer way to handle this.

Comment: Guava StripedLock or Interner?

Comment: It's not a good idea to a) involve the String pool in things it wasn't meant for b) create your own "clever" synchronization "solutions". See also in the linked question the statement: `As others have pointed out, using intern() for such a purpose and synchronizing on those Strings does indeed turn out to be a bad idea`.

Comment: static final Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lazyWeakLock(10); locks.get(id).lock(); ?

Comment: Do you really need lazy and weak locks?

Comment: We have thousands of ids, concurrent operations may be 10/20, i was thinking that a weak lock was better? am i wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124539/how-to-acquire-a-lock-by-a-key/11125602#11125602

Comment: Why do you think weak lock is better?

Answer (score 0):

StripedLock seems to be a good solution, better than guava's interner.

[How to acquire a lock by a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124539/how-to-acquire-a-lock-by-a-key/11125602#11125602)