# Thread and DB Transaction issue - make a check in Java db safe for multiple threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

**Context**:

- Spring Boot application with Spring JPA and MS SQL DB.
- User registration process with insuranceNumber
- insuranceNumber is not unique in DB but only for certain status (PROSPECTIVE, PARTICIPANT)
- there is a duplication check in a service to check this

```
    REST Controller -> 
            RegistrationService  (@Transactional)
                - do duplicate check (select * from customer where status in (PROSPECTIVE,PARTICIPANT) and insuranceNumber = XYZ -> no results good)
                - insert new customer to DB
```

**Issue**:

- If tested, the duplication checks works but sometimes I have duplicates of insuranceNumber in PROSPECTIVE status
- Assumption:

  - due to multiple REST requests in short time I have multiple threads (let's assume 3)
  - Thread 1 "duplicate check" - all fine
  - Thread 2 "duplicate check" - all fine (Thread 1 is not comitted yet)
  - Thread 1 insert do DB, commit TX
  - Thread 2 insert do DB, commit TX  ## the issue, now customer with same insurance number in same status
  - Thread 3 "duplicate check" - fails - als expected

**Possible Solutions:**

- Frontend: prevent this multiple requests. Out of scope. I want to be sure from backend
- DB: create something on DB site (database trigger) to do the same duplication check again. Feels wrong as it duplicates the logic of the duplication check. Would also raise a different exception than if raised in Java already
- Java code: RegistrationService with synchronized method. Would slow down registration for everybody. For me it would be enough that only one insurance number is allowed to enter the registration method.

Are there **more ideas?**
Play around with isolation levels for the DB?
Prevent to enter the registration method if one thread has already entered the method with same insurance number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The only reliable approach** to prevent duplicates in DB is to create unique index, in your particular case that should be [filtered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16) unique index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CUSTOMERS_UK  
ON CUSTOMERS(insuranceNumber)  
WHERE status IN ('PROSPECTIVE','PARTICIPANT')
```

Another options are:

- [application locks in MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [`lock by a key`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549978/3426309) in Java,  however, that won't work in case of multiple instance deployment

Comment: thanks so far. Didn't expect to use an index for such a constraint.
The "lock by a key" looks also interesting and will help with all further registration checks running in the same service.