# Scala Partial Function Application Semantics + locking with synchronized

Tags: scala, locking, synchronized, currying, partialfunction

Based on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507284/equivalence-lock-in-scala-java) on locks based on value-equality rather than lock-equality, I came up with the following implementation:

```
/**
  * An util that provides synchronization using value equality rather than referential equality
  * It is guaranteed that if two objects are value-equal, their corresponding blocks are invoked mutually exclusively.
  * But the converse may not be true i.e. if two objects are not value-equal, they may be invoked exclusively too
  * Note: Typically, no need to create instances of this class. The default instance in the companion object can be safely reused
  *
  * @param size There is a 1/size probability that two invocations that could be invoked concurrently is not invoked concurrently
  *
  * Example usage:
  *   import EquivalenceLock.{defaultInstance => lock}
  *   def run(person: Person) = lock(person) { .... }
  */
class EquivalenceLock(val size: Int) {
  private[this] val locks = IndexedSeq.fill(size)(new Object())
  def apply[U](lock: Any)(f: => U) = locks(lock.hashCode().abs % size).synchronized(f)
}

object EquivalenceLock {
  implicit val defaultInstance = new EquivalenceLock(1 << 10)
}
```

I wrote some tests to verify that my lock functions as expected:

```
import EquivalenceLock.{defaultInstance => lock}

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.collection.mutable

val journal = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

def log(msg: String) = journal.synchronized {
  println(msg)
  journal += msg
}

def test(id: String, napTime: Int) = Future {
  lock(id) {
    log(s"Entering $id=$napTime")
    Thread.sleep(napTime * 1000L)
    log(s"Exiting $id=$napTime")
  }
}

test("foo", 5)
test("foo", 2)

Thread.sleep(20 * 1000L)

val validAnswers = Set(
  Seq("Entering foo=5", "Exiting foo=5", "Entering foo=2", "Exiting foo=2"),
  Seq("Entering foo=2", "Exiting foo=2", "Entering foo=5", "Exiting foo=5")
)

println(s"Final state = $journal")
assert(validAnswers(journal))
```

The above tests works as expected (tested over millions of runs). But, when I change the following line:

```
def apply[U](lock: Any)(f: => U) = locks(lock.hashCode().abs % size).synchronized(f)
```

to this:

```
def apply[U](lock: Any) = locks(lock.hashCode().abs % size).synchronized _
```

the tests fail.

Expected:

```
Entering foo=5
Exiting foo=5
Entering foo=2
Exiting foo=2
```

OR

```
Entering foo=2
Exiting foo=2
Entering foo=5
Exiting foo=5
```

Actual:

```
Entering foo=5
Entering foo=2
Exiting foo=2
Exiting foo=5
```

The above two pieces of code should be the same and yet the tests (i.e. the `lock(id)` always enters concurrently for the same `id`) for the second flavor (the one with partial application) of code. Why?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918362/partial-function-application-prematurely-runs-codeblock-when-used-with-underscor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default function parameters are evaluated eagerly.  So

```
def apply[U](lock: Any) = locks(lock.hashCode().abs % size).synchronized _
```

is equivalent to

```
def apply[U](lock: Any)(f: U) = locks(lock.hashCode().abs % size).synchronized(f)
```

in this case f is evaluated before the synchronized block.