# How to avoid method execution from multiple threads with same parameter?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

How to avoid method  execution from multiple threads if they pass same parameter.
for example I have this method:

```
public void sync(int x){    

    //sync code -> write code here which is eligible for sync
}
```

If this method is running with parameter `x=5` and another request with same value `x=5` comes, it should be added in queue.

Comment: Basically this is **way too broad**. As in: there is no *simple* mechanism to do this. If you really have to **serialize** multiple threads on a parameter, then a single method taking an int parameter won't do. Because then you first have to design a solution with those multiple queues.

Comment: You can is BlockingQueue , which is there in java.util.concurrent package

Answer (score 3):

You can use [name-based lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639870/simple-java-name-based-locks).

```
public void sync(int x){
    Lock lock = new NameBasedLock(String.valueOf(x));
    lock.lock();
    try {
        doSomething();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply

```
   public synchronized void sync(int x){
       //Body of method
```

}

Comment: This avoid execution of sync method from multiple threads,but i want to avoid execution of a method only when it is passed  same parameter