# String literal synchronization

Tags: java

I'm trying to synchronize a String literal, so that I can control the execution of my threads but for some reason that does not work..

Is there any problem with the way its synchronized?

```
package scratch1;

public class OrderedThread {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RunThread first, second, third;
        OrderedThread orderedthread = new OrderedThread();
        first = new RunThread("One",orderedthread);
        second = new RunThread("Two",orderedthread);
        third = new RunThread("Three",orderedthread);
        second.start();
        first.start();
        third.start();
    }

    public void display(String msg){
        synchronized(msg){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
                System.out.println("Name = "+ msg);
            }
        }
    }

}

class RunThread extends Thread{
    String name;
    OrderedThread orderT;
    RunThread(String name, OrderedThread orderT){
        this.name = name;
        this.orderT = orderT;
    }

    public void run(){
        orderT.display(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are all synchronizing on different objects, so they each go through.

Comment: but I'm trying to synchronize on a string object?

Comment: `"One"`, `"two"`, `"three"` are not same String objects.

Comment: Also its generally bad practice to do synchronization yourself. Its beter to use the concurrence objects provided by Java (or some other library)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/synchronizing-on-string-objects-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of synchronization is access to shared resources. Your thread is supposed to acquire the monitor on an object that other threads are trying to access. In your case, each thread acquires a different object's monitor, so none of them blocks.

If instead you passed the literal `"One"` to your constructors

```
first = new RunThread("One",orderedthread);
second = new RunThread("One",orderedthread);
third = new RunThread("One",orderedthread);
```

Then you would see execution in order. Each thread would have to finish its for-loop (inside the `synchronized` block) before another one can start. This is because each Thread is synchronized on the same `String` object.

Better yet, use one of them many `java.util.concurrent` classes that act as locks. For example, [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).