# synchronized depended on string initilizing

Tags: java, string, synchronization

I'm trying to use String object as a lock (yes, I know it's not recommended - it's only for locks-understanding).

when initializing the lock when creating it, all works well:

code:

```
public class Action{

    String lock  = new String("hello");

    @Override
    public String myAction(long threadId){

        synchronized (lock) {
            i++;
            printToLog("thread " + threadId);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                printToLog("Thread "+threadId+ " could not sleep "+ e.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
            printToLog("Thread "+threadId+ " slept well! ");
        }
        return i+"";
    }

    private void printToLog(String messege) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        //get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        logger.info(messege + " at time: "+dateFormat.format(date));
    }

}
```

logs:

> [thread 555 at time: 2015/02/18 18:16:03]
>   [Thread 555 slept well! at time: 2015/02/18 18:17:43]
>   [thread 557 at time: 2015/02/18 18:17:43]
>   [Thread 557 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 18:19:23]
>   [thread 556 at time: 2015/02/18 18:19:23]
>   [Thread 556 slept well! at time: 2015/02/18 18:21:03]

but when I initialize the instance member lock within the method, it's as if the synch isn't working.

code:

```
public class Action{

    String lock;

    @Override
    public String myAction(long threadId){
        lock = new String("hello");
        synchronized (lock) {
            i++;
            printToLog("thread " + threadId);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                printToLog("Thread "+threadId+ " could not sleep "+ e.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
            printToLog("Thread "+threadId+ " slept well! ");
        }
        return i+"";
    }

    private void printToLog(String messege) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        //get current date time with Date()
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        logger.info(messege + " at time: "+dateFormat.format(date));
    }

}
```

logs:

> [thread 555 at time: 2015/02/18 19:17:35]
>   [thread 556 at time: 2015/02/18 19:17:40]
>   [thread 556 at time: 2015/02/18 19:17:41]
>   [thread 557 at time: 2015/02/18 19:17:44]
>   [thread 560 at time: 2015/02/18 19:17:48]
>   [Thread 555 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 19:19:15]
>   [Thread 556 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 19:19:20]
>   [Thread 556 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 19:19:21]
>   [Thread 557 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 19:19:24]
>   [Thread 560 slept well!  at time: 2015/02/18 19:19:28]

I don't understand what is the metter where I initiate the object? more - it's a string object so anyway it shouldn't be anyway the same reference? what am I misssing?

**Edit:** Yes, I accidentally swap the code.. that's what happens when you get "your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" too many times and then find out it was due to log lines :| will fix the swap.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I initialize the method". Can you post the code that creates and starts the threads for the two cases?

Comment: In your first example your `myAction` method creates each time separate lock object, so I doesn't stop other threads from using it since all of them will have new locks when using this method. In second case only one thread will be able to enter synchronized block because there will exist only one lock created before method could be invoked. In other words you can remove `lock` and synchronization mechanism from first code example and you should have same results.

Comment: @Moria: did you - by accident - swap the two code fragments?

Comment: You can do `Object lock = new Object()`, too. It avoids the "not recommended" bit of Strings.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: to be honest I don't see why a String is not recommended as a `lock` object. Since `Strings` are immutable, it is indeed not very common, but there is reason why not to do so...

Comment: @CommuSoft They are not recommended because you can get in trouble with interning when you don't realize it.  Simply using `String s = "foo"` can use a global String while in other instances it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, but from the moment you start reassigning objects. You must be careful. The same problems can for instance occur if you would use a *soft FlyWeight* pattern where unfrequently used objects are removed from the Weight.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the problem well enough.  Let's assume you have two classes A and B in the same package.  A defines `private final String foo = "foo"` and B defines `private final String foo = "foo"`.  Regardless of why someone decided to do this; even though both strings are private and in different classes (completely isolated) *they are the same object reference* so synchronizing on their own copy will collide with the other classes.

Comment: It's an issue with String interning and the mistake to assume different objects are created.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. What I meant to say, is that a `String` is not unique on that part. You can have the same issues with patterns like FlyWeight. The syntactical sugar that is used for strings makes it indeed a bit easier to make mistakes.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133988/synchronizing-on-string-objects-in-java

Answer (score 3):

(you probably swapped the code fragments).

I think you are missing an important aspect of [Java synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html). You don't use the **field** `lock` **as a lock**, you **assign a lock** to an instance. Or as said in the manual:

> Unlike synchronized methods, synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock

So what happens in your second (first in the question code fragment) is that **you create a new object**, namely:

```
lock = new String("hello");
```

And then you lock **on that object**. That means that every thread has a different instance on which it locks. And so there is no synchronization at all.

**EXAMPLE**: say you have two threads `t1` and `t2`. First we run a part of thread 1. Thread one calls the method and creates a `String` instance with value `"hello"`. So the memory looks like:

```
+------+                    +---------------+
|Action| <------------------+ thread memory |
+------+      +-------+     +---------------+
| lock------->|String |     
+------+      +-------+
              |"hello"|
              +-------+
```

Next you lock on that object, so - marked `lock` with a `&`, you get:

```
+------+                    +---------------+
|Action| <------------------+ thread memory |
+------+      +-------+     +---------------+
| lock------->|String | &     
+------+      +-------+
              |"hello"|
              +-------+
```

Now thread `t2` comes in. And the first thing `t2` does is creating a new object:

```
+------+                    +----------------+
|Action| <------------------+ thread2 memory |   (old object)
+------+      +-------+     +----------------+   +-------+
| lock------->|String |                          |String | &
+------+      +-------+                          +-------+
              |"hello"|                          |"hello"|
              +-------+                          +-------+
```

So the **new object is not locked**, and thread `t2` can continue it's execution.

---

It is however possible that you're code will indeed partly lock. It is for instance possible that thread `t1` could first create an object, then set `Action`'s field, then get suspended. Then `t2` becomes active, also creates an object, sets the `Action's` field and so both threads end up with the same **object**, but that's not very likely.

---

A final note is that there is **no problem using a "*`String` as a lock*"**. First of all you don't use a `String` as lock, you should see it as "locking" the string. So the virtual machine simply attaches information to the object that it is locked. There are thus no *good* or *bad* objects to get locked.

Comment: But what I don't understand is:  1) what does it matter where I initiate? the member isn't static and on both cases t1 and t2 will have each "their own" lock.  2)how can that be that each one of them have a different String? if they are using the same string-value, it should be referred to the same object in memory - isn't it? thanks!

Comment: The point is that you **instantiate a new object every time you call the method**. So instead of having one object shared by all threads, each thread generate its own object.